# Create datetime between two datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains:

```
StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime
```

I would like to be able to generate a timestamp between each `StartDate:StartTime and EndDate:EndTime`.

```
StartDate 2017-01-01 
StartTime 07:20:00 
EndDate 2017-01-15 
EndTime 15:00:00.
```

I would expect to generate each minute between 2017-01-01 07:20 and 2017-01-01 15:00 but for each date between 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-15.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you at least read the SQL Server documentation on dates manipulation?

Comment: you need to show expected results, but it sounds like you need a tally table and cross apply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38482580/6167855

Comment: @scsimon is spot on. A tally table is the way to do this. And of course that main table is kind of a mess. Storing dates and times as strings in the same table is just awful. If at all possible change your table to have two columns and change the datatype to datetime.

Answer (score 2):

This will be my third answer today that suggests setting up a Date Dimension / Calendar Table. This will make your life *tons* easier.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: highly agreed. Date Dimension table is a blessing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATE = '2017-01-01',
    @StartTime TIME(0) = '07:20:00',
    @EndDate DATE = '2017-01-15',
    @EndTime TIME(0) = '15:00:00';


DECLARE 
    @BegDT DATETIME2(0) = CAST(CONCAT(@StartDate, ' ', @StartTime) AS DATETIME2(0)),
    @EndDT DATETIME2(0) = CAST(CONCAT(@EndDate, ' ', @EndTime) AS DATETIME2(0));

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),
    cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(mi, @BegDT, @EndDT) + 1)
            DATEADD(mi, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @BegDT)
        FROM
            cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b
        )
SELECT 
    c.dt
FROM
    cte_Calendar c
WHERE 
    CAST(c.dt AS TIME(0)) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime;
```